# Why can I edit on main but not on meta?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, editing

On main, I can click on the "edit" link on a post to propose an edit.  On meta, it's not a link -- just text.  Why are the privileges different?  Or is this a bug?

Comment: Hey Monica! I think this link would prove useful to you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/165582

Comment: Oh thanks @Aarthi!  That answers my question.  I can't vote to close this as a cross-site duplicate, but I think it's useful to keep this breadcrumb here.  Hmm.  If you post that as an answer I can accept it. :-)

Comment: Copy the answer here and accept it yourself? :D

Comment: @Aarthi, I considered that, but isn't there a two-day delay on self-accepts?  I was hoping to resolve the question.

Comment: Ha, ok. There, I fixed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/165582):

> Mostly because the per-site metas are generally low traffic -- some of them count daily visits in the *dozens*.
>
> That means the moderators will have to do the work, since the 10k site users are the only ones that can even see this queue. And on many sites, like say Bicycles -- there are exactly zero users at this rep level, even after many months.
>
> https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all
>
> (highest rep on Bicycles as of the time I am writing is 5.6k)
>
> We were uncomfortable adding Yet Another Queue for Moderators to Look At across every site in the network.

Short version: it's `status-bydesign` because metas tend to not *need* a lot of edits in general.